# Combining MVVM, ORM and some hardware interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, mvvm

I'm trying to plan a architecture for a robot-controller application, which will be written in WPF. Since that MVVM is the *de facto* pattern for WPF, and in general is much more sexy I decided to use it as a base layout.

The application will have some controllers that access hardware, beyond the domainmodel that represents the database and utility classes. And for the database access I intend to use a Repository (coining Ayendes IRepository as the general idea), and then Linq2sql or EF4 for the actual access.

The application will also have it's own scripting engine, for custom scripts.

But what I'm unsure of, is if I should consider access to the hardware controllers and the scripting engine, to be part or below the domain model, or something that's directly accessed from the controller level.

I attempted to draw up what I think is the right way to do it. But I'm not at all sure it's the right way to go, so I would love some input and advice on this, and how I possible can do it better.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1744224/Upload/Drawing7.png

Comment: i think the arrow from ViewModel to View should not exist, am i wrong ?

Comment: @la mouette It's meant to be there. In WPF with MVVM the view and viewmodel communicate both ways with databindings.

Comment: Scripts are not persisted ? they are purely user input on which no value are added (reuse / version / checks) ? Hardware controller are mandatory or optional ? is there always Robot / Weight / Voice ?

Comment: Scripts will probably be saved on the filesystem and imported by the UI. The Scripting Engine will just get a string parameter, nothing else. The Robot/Weight/Voice controllers will always be modules that can be called.

Basically I'm wondering where to put "RobotController robot = new RobotController()". But as the robotcontroller have events that needs to update the UI, I figured that the controller is the optimal place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **absolutely** consider the low level controllers and scripting engine to be part of your domain model, however you should have these representated via abstractions (ie. with interfaces) so that you can properly test the rest of your domain.

I would also recommend against doing much more upfront design, and instead let your design evolve via TDD, otherwise you run the risk of trying to shoehorn an implementation in just to fit your UML diagrams...